# is Parse SDK iOS still working after migration ?

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, migration

As Parse announced that they will shut down their service at the beginning of 2017. How about their SDKs ? It will still work ?

I mean I have developed an iOS app with Parse.com Backend and i would like to know if i have to change the Queries (PFQuery) and all the other methods that i coded thanks to the iOS Parse SDK when the migration to "Heroku" for example will be done ?

Example:

## inParse

```
PFQuery*query = [PFQuery querywithclass@"xxxxx"];
[query findobjects];
```

## inHeroku will it be the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be work. You just have to change the Init. of Parse in your App to the new API URL.